# Compute "inwards derivative" of a 2d grid

Tags: python, numpy

I'll expose the problem in 2d, but need to eventually solve it in 3 dimensions.

Let's say I have the following grids

```
import numpy as np
ge = np.arange(36).reshape((6, 6))
gu = ge + 10
f = ge - 2*gu**2
```

Now `f` looks like this:

```
array([[ -200,  -241,  -286,  -335,  -388,  -445],
       [ -506,  -571,  -640,  -713,  -790,  -871],
       [ -956, -1045, -1138, -1235, -1336, -1441],
       [-1550, -1663, -1780, -1901, -2026, -2155],
       [-2288, -2425, -2566, -2711, -2860, -3013],
       [-3170, -3331, -3496, -3665, -3838, -4015]])
```

I can get the outer grid points as [via this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097068/how-to-get-boundaries-of-an-numpy-array) as:

```
def edge_mask(x):
    mask = np.ones(x.shape, dtype=bool)
    mask[x.ndim * (slice(1, -1),)] = False
    return mask
edge_mask(f)
Out[56]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Now, for all of these boundary points, I want to compute the "inward derivatives". For now, we can assume that the space between all grid points on `e` and `u` is one. Then, the grid inward derivative for `f[0, 1]` can be computed as

```
(-571-(-241))/(1) = -330
```

For the corner point `[0, 0]`, the inward derivative is w.r.t. the diagonal element `[1,1]`, and we can compute it here as

```
(-571 - (-200)/1 =  371
```

For `[4, 5]`, we have `(-2860-(-3838))/1 = 987`.

The main problem I'm facing is to compute the derivative in different directions, always inwards. Otherwise, this would simply be a case of `np.diff()`. What's an efficient way to do this that would also hold for at least 3 dimensions?

Comment: `np.gradient` is `np.diff` on steroids and might be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Using Till Hoffmann's great comment, I can at least  get almost there.

`gradient` get's the sign wrong when working with a binary matrix, but with integers we get

```
mask = edge_mask(f)
a, b = np.gradient(mask.astype(int))
```

which gives us the (inverse) sign (whether the derivative needs to be computed inwards or outwards):

```
a
Out[90]: 
array([[ 0. , -1. , -1. , -1. , -1. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. , -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  0. ]])
b
Out[91]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [-1. , -0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5,  1. ],
       [-1. , -0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5,  1. ],
       [-1. , -0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5,  1. ],
       [-1. , -0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5,  1. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

So then, we can do

```
-a * mask * np.gradient(f)[0]
Out[88]: 
array([[   0., -330., -354., -378., -402.,    0.],
       [   0.,   -0.,   -0.,   -0.,   -0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,  906.,  930.,  954.,  978.,    0.]])
-b * mask * np.gradient(f)[1]
Out[89]: 
array([[   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ -65.,   -0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,   81.],
       [ -89.,   -0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,  105.],
       [-113.,   -0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,  129.],
       [-137.,   -0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,  153.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.]])
```

All that is missing now, are the corners -- and I'm kind of stuck here.

Comment: Hm, the corners are tricky--especially if you don't just want to compute the first-order linear approximation. I don't know whether this will work for you, but you could try the following: get the diagonal of the matrix using `d = f[np.diag_indices_from(f)]` and then compute the derivative on `d`. That gives you the top left and bottom right corner. Then use the antidiagonal for the other two corners?

Comment: @TillHoffmann The problem will be doing this generically for `n` dimensions - or at least 3D, in a way that is compact and readable.